# iPhone - iOS4 - Movie Player - Fullscreen does not work

Tags: ios4, fullscreen, mpmovieplayer

I have implemented MPMoviePlayer functionality to play in landscape mode in iOS4- by reading information on other posts - thanks stackoverflow!

Basically I have a list of videos in tabular view and from that I can navigate to each video.

Problem I am facing is the video does play in fullscreen (landscape) however the top title bar and bottom navigation bars continue to be visible above the movie. I have tried to hide the bottom tabbar

```
[self.navigationController setHidesBottomBarWhenPushed:YES];    
[self.navigationController pushViewController:MstvideoplayerView animated:YES];
```

as well as tried to bring the movie subview to front

```
[[mpMoviePlayerControllerObj view] setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 480, 320)];
[[self view] bringSubviewToFront:[mpMoviePlayerControllerObj view]];  
mpMoviePlayerControllerObj.controlStyle = MPMovieControlStyleFullscreen;
```

However the top title bar (from movie list view) and bottom navigation bar still remain - on top of the movie player window.

How do I hide/get rid of these 2?

Answer (score 0):

If you call the UIViewControllers method
`presentModalViewController:(UIViewController *)modalViewController animated:(BOOL)animated`with the `MPMoviePlayerViewController`instance, it should present the movie player fullscreen